# How to implement news feed like Harvard and CNN app?

Tags: iphone, rss

i want to build an iphone app gets the news by using RSS feed , i know how to get a feed and purse ... etc

my problem is how can i build the news interface like CNN app and harvard app (i meant the design of interface)

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/207/photo1y.png/
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/94/photo2bn.png/

any tutorial will be helpful,
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no any specific components to display news like this. So you have to do it manually by using `UIScrollView`, `UIImage` and `UITableView`.

According to the CNN screenshot you have posted, Navigation bar is on the top with CNN logo and after that there is an `UIScrollView` to show the news sections. After that it placed a `UIImageView` and in the bottom of the screen it has a `UITableView` to display news items. There are lot of tutorials available to illustrate functionality of these components in web. Hope this will help you to construct your own view.